# iWatch: how to change label background color in iwatch

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I have added a label but not able to change the background color of this label in iWatch.

Can anyone help me out on this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to set the background color of WKInterfaceLabel. No such attribute provided by this class.

For more Info about WKInterfaceLabel read this link https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacelabel

Answer (score -1):

An alternative way is to put that label inside of a group (From the list of library) and give that group a color which changes the background color of the label in return.